# Cookie se almacena después de utilizarse la variable

Tags: php, cookies

Este es mi código de PHP

```
$lang = array();
if (empty($_COOKIE['lang']) || !isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
    setcookie('lang','es',time()+365*24*60*60,'/');
}
switch ($_COOKIE['lang']){
    ...
```

El error que tengo está en el `switch()`, y me da la sensación de que la cookie se almacena de forma asíncrona, es decir el switch se ejecuta antes de el "`setcookie()`".

El resultado de esto es que una vez que recargo la página me muestra el error siguiente:

```
Notice: Undefined index: lang in /var/www/html/assets/lang/lang.php on line 6
```

la primera recarga de la página me muestra el error pero si la vuelvo a recargar ya no me aparece porque ya si que se almacena la variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es así como funciona, seteas la cookie pero esta llega al navegador en las cabeceras de la página, luego al pedir otra página el navegador envía las cookies que tiene y ahi recién las ves en `$_COOKIE`

Por lo cual deberás tener en cuenta que en la primer carga de la página las cookies pueden no existir. Algo así:

```
$lang = array();

if (empty($_COOKIE['lang']) || !isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
    setcookie('lang','es',time()+365*24*60*60,'/');
    $cookieLang = "es";
} else {
  $cookieLang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
}

switch ($cookieLang){
   ...
```

Comment: Vale, muchísimas gracias. ^.^